# Redirect Page With JQuery In Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I wrote some code in Asp .net Core
At the bottom line I have a button that when clicked on it is directed to the Action Method by JQuery

```
<button onclick="Go('d6c00401-b95c-443b-8e30-769e6b5f8e03')">Click</button>
```

//J query

```
function Go(Id){                                                                    
 $.get("/Users/Test/"+Id)
}
```

// Action Method

```
public IActionResult Test(string Id){return View();}
```

But when I click the button, I get this error

//In the FireFox

**Uncaught SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal**

// In the Google Chrome

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For how to redirect to page by using Jquery,here is a working demo:

View:

```
<button onclick="Go('d6c00401-b95c-443b-8e30-769e6b5f8e03')">Click</button>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    function Go(Id) {
        $.get("/Users/Test/" + Id, function () {
            window.location.href = "Users/Test";
        })
    }
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test(string Id) { 
    return View(); 
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Result:
[image]